# how to add a default path to texmaker LaTeX

Tags: texmaker, texinputs

I am trying to add a path to texmaker (Texmaker 4.5 on OSX Sierra).
The reason is that i want to be able to do the same template doc every time so i dont have to re-import everything manually.
I successfully did for org-mode, but i could not find the way to do it in LaTeX directly.

Any lead please?

Comment: As per my understanding you want all your LaTeX projects to import the same preamble file so that all get the changes automatically if you update it? In Linux I'd solve this with a symlink (to an outside folder) and on Windows with a Junction tothe same, so that the  preamble.tex  seems to be in a project sub folder.

Comment: Yes, that's about what i need.  Essentially i want LaTeX to have a path defined by default where i can post all the templates i want to be using in new documents for example using '\input{myTemplateFile.tex}' so that this myTemplateFile.tex has in store all the titles, logo, etc. that i want to see in my new project.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to create the symlink or junction beside the new `main.tex` when you start a new project?

Comment: a more complex alternative could be a git sub-repository for the `myTemplateFile.tex`. this could be fetched from the central git repository independent of the rest of the project.

Comment: Not sure how to do this.  I was thinking that i could have used some ./bash_profile file in which i indicate the path.  It worked fine in org mode (invoked with #+LaTeX_HEADER: \input{heading.txt} for ex.).
Maybe a symlink would work out in LaTeX if no other solution is available.  
So i think i could try the symlink, how do i do that please ?

Comment: *"So i think i could try the symlink, how do i do that please"* see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution 1: *symlink*

create this folder structure:

```
template/
    myTemplateFile.tex
project1/
    myProjectFile.tex
    template->../template
project2/
    myProjectFile.tex
    template->../template
```

to create the symlinks go into the projectX folders and type
`ln -s ../template template`

then in `myProjectFile.tex` reference the template as
`\input{template/myTemplateFile.tex}`

---

solution 2: *git*

- create a (remote) git repository for your template file. (eg. https://github.com/someuser/template.git)
- create a new local git repository for your new project.
  `git init .`
- checkout the template repository as git submodule:
  `git submodule add https://github.com/someuser/template.git template`

content of the project main file looks the same in both approaches:
`\input{template/myTemplateFile.tex}`

single users should prefer the symlink apprach, for multiple users prefer the git approach.